# EF Core EnsureCreated() only creates the first DbContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm having an interesting issue were two `EnsureCreated()` calls only create the first `DbContext`.

The issue only happens on my tests, because my default database were done with Migrations.

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var dbUser = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<UserTrackerContext>();
                var dbRefresh = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<RefreshTokenContext>();

                dbRefresh.Database.EnsureCreated();
                dbUser.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my WebApplicationFactory, that gets called by tests.
The issue only happened at CI, a new SQL Server was created on docker, and only the "dbRefresh" table were added. No sign, or error of the "dbUser" table.
It's just not there, and breaks only when the tests hits it.
Both `DbContext` uses the same connection string in the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Both DbContext uses the same connection string in the tests."

The Database name is in the connection string.

Comment: Yes, can't I use the same database name for both?

Comment: Oh the EnsureCreated is for the whole database, not just the table.

Comment: Yes.  If you have multiple DbContexts that share a database you should create an uber-DbContext to use in database creation/migration.